Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d with python ver3.7
i want to install open3d on windows and my python version is 3.12.1
error
I saw some solutions on other pages (like installing version 3.7, pip3, etc.) and tried them, but they didn't work. please explain the solution to me simply cuz i'm new to python.

i know there is a similar topic but i can't comment, apologize.

It appears support for Python 3.12 is in progress, but not yet available. https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/pull/6717 . Currently 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 are supported. https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/getting_started.html . Solution would be to install one of those supported python versions.

This question is similar to: Can't install open3d libraries (Error:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it only supports till python 3.11 for now.
https://pypi.org/project/open3d/

You need to work with python 3.11 until 3.12 is supported.
get python 3.11 from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/
